# How to debug when an app is launched with URL Scheme from Safari

Tags: iphone

I want to test my app for my app launched with a URL scheme from Safari, how can that be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the answer to this question:

[Debugging App When Launched by Push Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239000/debugging-app-when-launched-by-push-notification)

It's a different question but the same answer. In summary you select the "Start executable after starting debugger" option in XCode, but the original answer is good so I won't duplicate it entirely!