# Attach XCode Debugger

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

I'm developing an iPhone app that needs a web login.
As usual I call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:loginURL];
```

This close the app and calls the login page inside Safari.
Once logged, the app is opened once again using a callback address and the iPhone URL registration feature.

The question here is:

*Since the app is closed when I call Safari, the debug stops. How can I continue the debug?*

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, however, get XCode to connect to an application the next time it's launched. You bring up the inspector on your executable and check the "Wait for next launch/push notification" box. This is explained in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239000/debugging-app-when-launched-by-push-notification/1239555#1239555).

The other alternative would be to use a `UIWebView` inside your app rather than switching to Safari.