# How to launch an app in debug mode from xcode with a URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode

Is there a way for xcode to launch an application with an app URL?

I've read the answer to this question [Debugging App When Launched by Push Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239000/debugging-app-when-launched-by-push-notification), and it works great for single tests.

I'm trying to write unit tests for launching the app with lots of different URLs, and using the previous method will be pretty hard to automate.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search the docs for "shell script build phase".

Comment: Slightly overkill for my immediate needs, but we're planning on implementing an automated build process for iphone anyway, so what better time than the present I suppose.  Thanks for the tip.  For anyone who doesn't want to search the docs, here's the current link http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/200-Build_Phases/bs_build_phases.html