# Debugger in an iPhone app session not launched from tapping a springboard icon

Tags: iphone, xcode, gdb

I'm trying to debug an issue that only occurs when my iPhone app receives a push notification.

The trouble is I can't figure out how to get a debugger, or even view any `NSLog` output, when my app is launched in this way.  Xcode gives me a debugger and the gdb console when it launches an app for me.

So how do I run my app in the debugger when Xcode does not launch my app for me?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239000/debugging-app-when-launched-by-push-notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked and answered at [Debugging App When Launched by Push Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239000/debugging-app-when-launched-by-push-notification)

See also the Apple documentation at  http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeProjectManagement/230-Defining_Executable_Environments/executable_environments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002698-CJBICGJI