# Console readout after app is killed

Tags: ios, xcode

We are testing deep links and need to get print statements as the app is starting up. The app needs to be opened using a link not run as it is connected to Xcode. Since, it is not connected to Xcode, we are not able to see the console read out. How would we access the read out while the app is running? The phone is connected to the computer, but the app is killed because it needs to be launched using a deep link. We are using swift.

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29853913/1187415 ?

Comment: Yes but it does not allow you to see the console read out using that method.