# Not getting the logs on navigator panel in xcode when app quits

Tags: xcode

I did Not get the logs on navigator panel in Xcode(9.2) when the user quits the app forcefully and relaunching it again. I have tried it using both simulator(8.4) and device(11.2.2) but still not get the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are force quitting an application that you are running through Xcode, the console will quit as well and terminate the current run session (typically with a final log statement notifying you of such termination i.e. `Program ended with exit code: 9`).

Once the application resigns as a "running" app, that's it.

If you are looking for background debugging or manually launching the app, [this may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239000/debugging-app-when-launched-by-push-notification) better understand.